# hyperledger fabric Failed to generate orderer genesis block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Generated byfn.sh my first network, the emergence of configtxgen can not generate genesis block.
My error is as follows:

```
[root@demo first-network]# ./byfn.sh generate
Generating certs and genesis block for with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
/storage/u01/hyperledger/bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
org1.example.com
org2.example.com

/storage/u01/hyperledger/bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
2018-02-26 11:00:08.152 CST [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2018-02-26 11:00:08.155 CST [common/configtx/tool/localconfig] Load -> CRIT 002 Error unmarshaling config into struct:  4 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: capabilities
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsChannel].Application' has invalid keys: Capabilities
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis]' has invalid keys: Capabilities
* 'Profiles[TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis].Orderer' has invalid keys: Capabilities
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

my docker version :

```
Docker version 17.03.1-ce
```

my go version:

```
go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64
```

my os version:

centos 7.2

my configtx.yaml as follow picture show:

[image: configtx.yaml screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

Re download platform-specific binaries with 1.1.0 (Not 1.0.6) -> OK

curl -sSL [download script][1] | bash -s 1.1.0

Comment: I am using **1.1.0**  version `curl -sSL [google url] | bash -s 1.1.0  1.1.0  0.4.6` and still getting same error

Answer (score 8):

`Capabilities` keyword was introduced for v1.1.0-preview and later. Hence I'd guess you trying to use binary of version v1.0.0 with configuration file of v1.1.0.

Comment: Same issue here and using diff version of the fabric-samples repo  "git checkout -b v1.0.6" worked for me, thanks !

Comment: Hi there I am getting the same problem described here. My configtx.yaml has the Capabilities section, and I am on release 1.1. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version. It should be 8.x.
The below link should help.
https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-install-specific-nodejs-version-c6e1cec8aa11

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please embed the essential party of the 3rd party source into your answer for the 3rd party resource might vanish.